# Score a hand of Hearts

Tags: code-golf, card-games

[Hearts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts) is a trick-taking card game for 4 players. Each trick is taken by the player who played the highest card of the leading suit. At the end of each hand, the players incur a penalty score depending on the penalty cards they have taken; the task is to determine the scores under [Microsoft Hearts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Hearts) rules.

### Input

Input is 4 lists (or delimited string, array, etc.) showing the penalty cards taken by each of the 4 players. The penalty cards are

```
2♥, 3♥, 4♥, 5♥, 6♥, 7♥, 8♥, 9♥, 10♥, J♥, Q♥, K♥, A♥, Q♠
```

which we shall represent as

```
2,  3,  4,   5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,  11, 12,  13,  1,  0
```

respectively.

### Output

Output is the 4 penalty points incurred by the 4 players (list, string, array etc.). Scoring is as follows:

- Each heart (`♥`, represented by integers `1` to `13` inclusive) incurs 1 point
- The queen of spades (`Q♠`, represented by `0`) incurs 13 points
- Exception: if a player has taken all of the penalty cards (called shooting the moon), then he incurs 0 points, while all other players incur 26 points.

### Test cases

```
[2, 8, 7, 1], [3, 4], [], [9, 5, 6, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13]     -->  4,  2,  0, 20
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [], [], [1]   --> 25,  0,  0,  1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0], [], [], [] -->  0, 26, 26, 26
```

**Shortest code in bytes wins.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CJam, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to jimmy23013 for saving 2 bytes.*

```
{{XD?}f%1fb_26&1bf^}
```

An unnamed block (function), which takes a list of 4 lists as input and returns the list of scores.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4ve34KCnt7WEQ_fWYlMWZiXzI2JjFiZl59Cgp-cH0v&input=W1syIDggNyAxXSBbMyA0XSBbXSBbOSA1IDYgMCAxMCAxMSAxMiAxM11dCltbMCAyIDMgNCA1IDYgNyA4IDkgMTAgMTEgMTIgMTNdIFtdIFtdIFsxXV0KW1sxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOSAxMCAxMSAxMiAxMyAwXSBbXSBbXSBbXV0)

#### Explanation

```
{      e# For each card...
  XD?  e#   Choose 1 if it's positive and 13 if it's zero.
}f%
1fb    e# Sum each hand.
_26&   e# Get the set intersection of the scores with 26. This gives [26]
       e# if someone shot the moon, and [] otherwise.
1b     e# Treat as base-1 digits, which gives 26 if someone shot the moon
       e# and zero otherwise.
f^     e# XOR each result with this number. This swaps zeros and 26s when 
       e# someone shot the moon and does nothing otherwise.
```

Comment: `_26&1b`. -2 bytes.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Ahhhh, `1b`... I was trying to find a short way to turn `[26]` into `26` and `[]` into `0` but somehow that didn't occur to me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

### R, <strike>85 77</strike> 74 bytes

```
function(x,z=sapply(x,function(x)sum(x>0)+any(x<1)*13))abs(z-any(z>25)*26)
```

Unnamed function that takes an R-list as input. Works by counting the number of elements `>0` and adds 13 if any element within each vector is `<1` (i.e. queen of spades) and store as `z`.

If any element in `z` is `>25`, return `26-z`, else return `z`.

[Try it on R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=gCETKMSR&version=2)

Comment: Would `26-z` work?

Comment: @lastresort Yes of course. /facepalm

Answer (score 4):

## C++14, 158 bytes

As unnamed Lambda:

```c++
[](auto c){typename decltype(c)::value_type r;int b=0;for(auto d:c){int q=0;for(auto i:d)q+=i?1:13;r.push_back(q);b+=q==26;}if(b)for(int&x:r)x=26-x;return r;}
```

Requires a `vector<vector<int>>` and returns `vector<int>`

Ungolfed:

```c++
[](auto c){
 typename decltype(c)::value_type r;   //result vector
 int b=0;                              //flag if one has all cards
 for(auto d:c){                        //over all decks
  int q=0;                             //count points
  for(auto i:d) q+=i?1:13;             //+13 for queen, +1 else
  r.push_back(q);                      //add to result
  b+=q==26;                            //possibly activate flag
 }
 if(b) for(int&x:r) x=26-x;            //if flag is set, mirror the results
 return r;
}
```

Few testcases for you:

```c++
 auto r = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{2,8,7,1},{3,4},{},{9,5,6,0,10,11,12,13}};
 auto s = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0},{},{},{}};
 auto t = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{},{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0},{},{1}};
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, <s>75</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```python
i=[len(a)+12*(0in a)for a in input()]
print[[x,26-x][26in i]for x in i]
```

Takes input as `[2, 8, 7, 1], [3, 4], [], [9, 5, 6, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

Comment: Could you save 3 characters by using 12*[0in a] instead of [0,12][0in a]?

Comment: @Costantino I think you mean `12*(0in a)`.

Comment: `print[[x,26-x][26in i]for x in i]` is one byte shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```
f x|all(<26)x=x|0<1=map(26-)x
f.map(sum.map((13^).(0^)))
```

Usage:

```
> f.map(sum.map((13^).(0^))) $ [[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [], [], [1]]
[25,0,0,1]
```

Comment: I think you can write `f` as `f n=13^0^n`.

Comment: @xnor I think you're right. Saves 3 bytes.

Comment: I think defining `f x|all(<26)x=x|0<1=map(26-)x` and using it in place of the lambda function saves some bytes.

Comment: @Zgarb right you are, I'd say that's another 3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 113 bytes

```
function h($a){foreach($a as&$b)$b=count($b)+12*in_array(0,$b);if(max($a)>25)foreach($a as&$n)$n=26-$n;return$a;}
```

function takes an array of arrays, returns an array of values.

---

Marvel the other array mapping in PHP: loops with referenced items. Waaay shorter than `array_map`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>26</del> <del>22</del> 21 bytes

Trailing whitespace must be removed from input so that it is interpreted as an array.
The ending was inspired of the other answers when using (26-x) when a player gathered all penalty cards.

```
vy0å12*yg+})D26©åi(®+

v                    For each array
 y                   Push array on the stack
  0å                 Generate a boolean array indicating whether the queen of spades is at the same index in the original array
    12*              Multiply by 12 the value of the queen of spades
       yg+           Add the length of the array; the queen of spades gets her last point from this part
          }          End for
           )         Push an array of all evaluated scores
            D26©å    1 if there is a 26, 0 otherwise
                 i   If there is a 26
                  (®+ Mirror the array: for each element yield 26-element
                      Implicit end if
                      Implicitly print the score array
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnkww6UxMip5Zyt9KUQyNsKpw6VpKMKuKw&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwLCAxMSwgMTIsIDEzLCAwXSwgW10sIFtdLCBbXQ)

It still looks pretty golfable, with duplicated constants and conditional statements.

## Former version, 26 bytes

(One byte for each point in maximal penalty value)

I decided to keep it as its length fits best this challenge in my opinion :) .

```
vyD0å12*sg+})D26©QDOi_®*ë\
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnlEMMOlMTIqc2crfSlEMjbCqVFET2lfwq4qw6tc&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwLCAxMSwgMTIsIDEzLCAwXSwgW10sIFtdLCBbXQ)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>82</s> <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```js
f = 
s=>s.map(c=>c.map(t=>r+=t?1:13,r=0)|(b|=r>25,r),b=0).map(c=>b*26^c)

console.log(f.toString().length)
console.log(f([[2, 8, 7, 1], [3, 4], [], [9, 5, 6, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13]]));
console.log(f([[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [], [], [1] ]));
console.log(f([[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [], [1], [] ]));
console.log(f([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0], [], [], []]));
console.log(f([[],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0], [], []]));
```

#### Breakdown

```
s=>s.map(                              // for each hand
 c=>c.map(                             // for each card
  t=>r+=t?1:13,                        // add value of card
 r=0)|(
  b=b|r>25,r                           // set flag if any hand scores 26 points
 ),
 b=0)
.map(c=>b?                             // for every card if a hand scored 26
  c?0:26                               // set every 0 hand to 26 and the 26 hand to 0
:c)                                    // otherwise do nothing
```

Comment: `c=>b*26^c` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: `s=>s.map(b=c=>c.map(t=>r+=t?1:13,r=0)|(b|=r>25,r)).map(c=>b*26^c)`?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 101 bytes

```
def s(a):r=[sum([(1,13)[c==0]for c in h])for h in a];s=(r,[(26,0)[s==26]for s in r]);return s[26in r]
```

Full code:

```
def score(hands):
    result = [sum([(1, 13)[card == 0] for card in hand]) for hand in hands]
    results = (result, [(26, 0)[score == 26] for score in result])
    return results[26 in result]
```

Comment: `12*(c<1)+1` is 2 bytes shorter than `(1,13)[c==0]`. `26*(s>25)` is 3 bytes shorter than `(26,0)[s==26]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 59 bytes

```
->a{a.map{|h|a.max.size>13?h.min||26:h.size+12*h.count(0)}}
```

Or, alternatively,

```
->a{a.map{|h|a.count([])>2?h.min||26:h.size+12*h.count(0)}}
```

If only one hand has any cards, we want the empty hands to get a value of 26, and the hand with cards to get a value of 0. I do this by calling `min` on the hands - this returns `nil` for an empty array, and then I `||` it into 26. In other cases, I count the number of cards in a hand and then add 12 to the Queen of Spades.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 28 bytes

27 bytes of code, +1 for `-p` flag.

```
Y{$+1+12*!*a}M Va26Ny?26-yy
```

Takes input on the command-line as a string representing a nested list, like `"[[2 8 7 1] [3 4] [] [9 5 6 0 10 11 12 13]]"` (quotes not needed on TIO). [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=WXskKzErMTIqISphfU0gVmEyNk55PzI2LXl5&input=&args=LXA+W1tdIFsyIDggNyAxIDMgNCA1IDYgMCAxMCAxMSAxMiAxM10gW10gWzldXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
ƛ0c12*nL+;:26c[26꘍
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGmzBjMTIqbkwrOzoyNmNbMjbqmI0iLCIiLCJbW10sIFsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMCwgMTEsIDEyLCAxMywgMF0sIFtdLCBbXV0iXQ==) or [run all the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQaiIsIjrGmyIsIsabMGMxMipuTCs7OjI2Y1syNuqYjSIsIl07WsabYCA9PiBgaiIsIltbWzIsIDgsIDcsIDFdLCBbMywgNF0sIFtdLCBbOSwgNSwgNiwgMCwgMTAsIDExLCAxMiwgMTNdXSwgW1swLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMCwgMTEsIDEyLCAxM10sIFtdLCBbXSwgWzFdXSwgW1swLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMCwgMTEsIDEyLCAxM10sIFtdLCBbMV0sIFtdXSwgW1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMCwgMTEsIDEyLCAxMywgMF0sIFtdLCBbXSwgW11dLCBbW10sWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwLCAxMSwgMTIsIDEzLCAwXSwgW10sIFtdXV0iXQ==).

### How?

```
ƛ0c12*nL+;:26c[26꘍
ƛ                   # For each inner list in the (implicit) input:
 0c                 # Does it contain a zero (the queen of spades)?
   12*              # Multiply this by 12 (aka if it contains a zero, then 12, otherwise 0)
      nL+           # Add the length of the inner list to this
         ;          # Close map lambda
          :         # Duplicate
           26c      # Does it contain 26? (aka someone shot the moon)
              [26꘍  # Then bitwise XOR each with 26 (swapping 26 and 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 93 bytes

```
a=>{val% =a.map(_.map{case 0=>13;case _=>1}sum)
if(%toSet 26)%map{case 0=>26;case _=>0}else%}
```

Usage:

```
val f:(Seq[Seq[Int]]=>Seq[Int])=...
f(Seq(Seq(2, 8, 7, 1), Seq(3, 4), Seq(), Seq(9, 5, 6, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13)))
```

Explanation:

```
a=>{           //define an anonymou function with a parameter a
  val% =         //define % as...
    a.map(         //map each element of a...
      _.map{         //to each of the card
        case 0=>13     //replaced with its value
        case _=>1
      }
      sum            //and the sum of the values
    )
  if(            //if
    %toSet 26      //one player has all cards
  )
    %map{          //return % with...
      case 0=>26     //each 0 replaced with 26
      case _=>0      //and everything else (aka the 26) replaced 0
    }
  else           //else
    %              //return %
}
```

I could use `%toSet 26` instead of `% contains 26` because `Set`'s `apply` method is `contains` and not get-at-index like `Seq`'s