# Heart Point Generator

Tags: code-golf, array, card-games

It's mentioned last time that, in [Hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lady),

> Each round every player gets a non-negative amount of *points*. The sum of the points is 26, and at least one player gets 13 or more points.

Actually, it's the game part:

1. Average the 52 cards (♠♡♢♣ * 23456789 10 JQKA) to the 4 players
2. The player with a ♣2(the smallest value) starts the first hand
3. The player who play a largest value with same suit to the hand starter on `i`-th hand (`1<=i<=13`):

- Add 1 to his point for each ♡ in this hand
- Add 13 to his point if ♠Q is in this hand
- starts `(i+1)`th hand (`1<=i<=12`)

There's some playing rules:

1. On the first hand, ♣2 should be played.
2. If possible, no ♡ or ♠Q on the first hand.
3. If possible, non-starter should play starter's suit
4. If possible, the hand starter can't play ♡ if it isn't played.

Now given the point of 4 players, generate a valid game that lead to the point result. You can assume that it's possible. Output is flexible, you can choose any 52 values to mean the 52 cards (This is the explained output below, so there's no fear that you have to encode the output in a specific way)

Sample:

```
Input 13   0   0  13
Hand1 ♣5 [♣2] ♣3  ♣4
    2[♣9] ♣8  ♣7  ♣6
    3[♣A] ♣10 ♣J  ♣Q
    4[♣K] ♡10 ♡J  ♡Q
    5[♢7] ♢5  ♢4  ♢6
    6[♢A] ♢3  ♡A  ♢2
    7[♢K] ♡8  ♡7  ♡6
    8[♢Q] ♡5  ♡4  ♡3
    9[♢J] ♡2  ♠4  ♡9
   10[♢10]♡K  ♠6  ♠7
   11[♢9] ♠8  ♠10 ♠9
   12[♢8] ♠J  ♠A  ♠K
   13[♠3] ♠5  ♠2  ♠Q
                 [  ]
```

Sample:

```
Input 26   0   0   0
Hand1 ♣5 [♣2] ♣3  ♣4
    2[♣9] ♣8  ♣7  ♣6
    3[♣A] ♣10 ♣J  ♣Q
    4[♣K] ♡10 ♡J  ♡Q
    5[♢7] ♢5  ♢4  ♢6
    6[♢A] ♡K  ♢3  ♢2
    7[♢K] ♡8  ♡7  ♡6
    8[♢Q] ♡5  ♡4  ♡3
    9[♢J] ♡2  ♡A  ♡9
   10[♢10]♠5  ♠6  ♠7
   11[♢9] ♠8  ♠10 ♠9
   12[♢8] ♠J  ♠A  ♠K
   13[♠Q] ♠4  ♠3  ♠2
     [  ]
```

Sample:

```
Input 23   1   1   1
Hand1 ♣4 [♣2] ♣3  ♣5
    2 ♡2  ♣8  ♣7 [♣6]
    3 ♡3  ♣10 ♣J [♣9]
    4 ♡4  ♣A [♣Q] ♣K
    5 ♡6 [♡5] ♢4  ♢6
    6[♡A] ♢2  ♢3  ♢5
    7[♡7] ♢7  ♢8  ♢9
    8[♡8] ♢10 ♢J  ♢Q
    9[♡9] ♢K  ♢A  ♠Q
   10[♡10]♠5  ♠6  ♠7
   11[♡J] ♠8  ♠10 ♠9
   12[♡Q] ♠J  ♠A  ♠K
   13[♡K] ♠4  ♠3  ♠2
     [  ]
```

Here a `[]` means starter, which you needn't output. Also it's absolutely not a game that would happen in real play, but it's just valid.

This is code-golf, shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: [Reverse question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99716) though I still take Shoot the moon as [26,0,0,0]

Comment: so the input is a list of points?

Comment: @DialFrost Input 4 points, fine to be a list

Comment: I may be wrong because I've never played Hearts, but shouldn't `♢7` have won round 5 of both examples?

Comment: @jezza_99 Fixed, manual test data is buggy

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 676 bytes

```
R=range
def f(s):
    c,y=[0,13]+([2,1,2,2][(i:=s[0]==14):i+3],[2,2,1])[s[0]%2]+[1]*8,[]
    r=p=0
    for j,i in enumerate(c):
        r+=i
        if r==s[p]:y.append(j+1);r=0;p+=1
    p,t=y[:-1],c[2:5]
    h=[[(1,12)]+[(0,12),(0,11)]+[(0,9-x)for x in R(10)],[(1,0)]+[(2,x+1)for x in R(12)],[(1,11),(0,10)]+[(3,0),(3,1)]+[(1,x+1)for x in R(9)],[(1,10),(2,0)]+[(3,12-x)for x in R(11)]]
    for i in R(len(p)):
        k=p[i]
        if i==0:h[0][k],h[1][1]=h[1][1],h[0][k]
        if i==1:q=p[0];h[1],h[2]=h[1][:q]+h[1][q+1:k+1]+[h[2][k-1]]+h[1][k+1:],h[2][:q]+[h[1][q]]+h[2][q:k-1]+h[2][k:]
        if i==2:h[2],h[3]=h[2][:-1]+[h[3][-1]],h[3][:k]+[h[2][-1]]+h[3][k:-1]
    h[2][2:5]=[sorted(h[2][2:5]).pop(1-i)for i in t]
    return h
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=zVbJjuM2EEWCXNpfwXEQmLTKhin3qgYPuWU5pZEbQTQESW7LiyRTNNqdwXzIIJfO-lFznC9JFSkv3UkGyC2AbVJVr-rVRso__9k8uXldPX_44i4vZqxJbVvwNqttAfO0yluR9M6y1Oat6scwhXO4gEu4gmu4ATmB7-AH-B6-7o_bZlU63oe-6J2129Ih_OP7Z_j4_jf8_orfX15iGltWjs_631bN1iXs7WAwXtRlxfmADaLWWV66Yi3EeLXYto5fAIoFm9WWkZyVFfMhinfME7rUusIq2TvzEHhI18W9rbdVTtCi2q4Lm7qC_1Q2fBjSory6KPjgGxSxwZCXSk1EoI8kslvPfunZ4RCi7jNMQveNRnzHbSKftV6YyFdLL00UcOYl7p9SAr6ApXgZ6jEFITDFM7-9JxJ1VOm9Vz0xiHksqwrLoCkCVs6YR_8LnBWrtmAj6SMgIASrih3x5HNf2-B7XFZ5sePrdMeDQBx6iekMryJMeXgx7IyivmbMYIdosrJ5kS3vfdtez9dJ_6riMWBahUEOz_9rR9M87-xPKggdARy9_89Lagu3tRU7xutL-InkIJwHKiZtNH9MlOYTyITe_D1eitZQlBvIXsUnTuMRwkSYO6IJ_Bo6znBxfCoiOR1yJJMT8QIh_ti62ej6w-e_3ymbVg-Fz2LGw6UCT9hikFMTcR2DhBhio3mZqBb5lJLnIimjqQFUotoITfKvYjxX0gyvQWMprWrUJIzIAsqXk5H5ebCRKnHBzlk8g7oxydM4bZqiyvkCj_itVZPbJqLJa8CpJ52MpIFMx8kFup8rrbkEGWMZqJi4AVpk93wz2gni3hHzHcf0MVo0mHh9DDtkONXHnR4dQCgX4aaIB_wNXuVrq5u9EaFi2NvI-BU5mpvutATJqqh4E07FUjW6NKEOdMclcywlXlEwx1riR3UrdPIDUiYbNJ2Y23nQxh002ZjIbzaRTJaRxJhIqZdYvk6D0iSYeLQOcK9F0SYhaNgvkyNhnJAIzabERLaj4HxqNPn2Gp0s94Qd35S84B57RlJqn9Jtjccs5weJGDd1w-WoFIcqOXM4a_NuWD9Lv2Q_Fq0rq4fezNZreuNYV9erlpXrBl0Oe1na0v1kev5U4AO50rO6ZqeCxtb5NnNcD_3sczmF-IqauX8-_9SDCLfNmpM7gYW5ZPSS4siCJyRk5lU6ocQFVeKNkgbbjYY-hqp2FIePlqbAb_bT7219Ag6TPcWhOYneqNMbmyQw8wuO1P7tTXUKXIO3pHo3YLO0XBU53vnhn4R3igOEtvut6K6F5-ew_gU)

Takes the input as a reverse sorted list of scores. Returns a list of the cards in each hand, ordered by round. Cards are encoded as `(suit, value)`, where `suit` and `value` are indexes of `"♠♣♢♡"` and `['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']`  respectively. Works by rearranging the master arrangement

```
Hand 1  ♣A  [♣2]  ♣K   ♣Q  
     2 [♠A]  ♢3   ♠Q   ♢2  
     3 [♠K]  ♢4   ♡2   ♡A  
     4 [♠J]  ♢5   ♡3   ♡K  
     5 [♠10] ♢6   ♣3   ♡Q  
     6 [♠9]  ♢7   ♣4   ♡J  
     7 [♠8]  ♢8   ♣5   ♡10 
     8 [♠7]  ♢9   ♣6   ♡9  
     9 [♠6]  ♢10  ♣7   ♡8  
    10 [♠5]  ♢J   ♣8   ♡7  
    11 [♠4]  ♢Q   ♣9   ♡6  
    12 [♠3]  ♢K   ♣10  ♡5  
    13 [♠2]  ♢A   ♣J   ♡4  
       [  ]
```

as needed to give the correct score.

Interestingly, I believe there are only 87 unique test cases. This is based on the assumption that `[n,n,n,1]` is an impossible score, as it is impossible for the lowest scoring hand to win a trick without gaining a score of two or having an illegal move prior. However, I'm not confident in this assumption, so may need to alter my solution if proven wrong.

I'm very confident that there is a better master arrangment and rearrangment method, and will update if I find it.

## Explanation

```
R=range
def f(s):
    c,y=[0,13]+([2,1,2,2][(i:=s[0]==14):i+3],[2,2,1])[s[0]%2]+[1]*8,[]  # Find the scoring arrangment per round
    r=p=0
    for j,i in enumerate(c):                                            # Find which rounds the next player takes over winning tricks
        r+=i
        if r==s[p]:y.append(j+1);r=0;p+=1                               
    p,t=y[:-1],c[2:5]                                                   # Rounds the next player takes over, adjustment needed at end to account for scoring arrangment
    h=[                                                                 # Master hand arrangment
    [(1,12)]+[(0,12),(0,11)]+[(0,9-x)for x in R(10)],
    [(1,0)]+[(2,x+1)for x in R(12)],
    [(1,11),(0,10)]+[(3,0),(3,1)]+[(1,x+1)for x in R(9)],
    [(1,10),(2,0)]+[(3,12-x)for x in R(11)]
    ]
    for i in R(len(p)):
        k=p[i]
        if i==0:h[0][k],h[1][1]=h[1][1],h[0][k]                                                                         # Rotation from first player to second player
        if i==1:q=p[0];h[1],h[2]=h[1][:q]+h[1][q+1:k+1]+[h[2][k-1]]+h[1][k+1:],h[2][:q]+[h[1][q]]+h[2][q:k-1]+h[2][k:]  # Rotation from second player to third player
        if i==2:                                                                                                        # Rotation from third player to fourth player
            h[0],h[3]=h[0][:p[0]+1]+h[3][p[0]+1:],h[3][:p[0]+1]+h[0][p[0]+1:]
            h[2],h[3]=h[2][:-1]+[h[3][-1]],h[3][:k]+[h[2][-1]]+h[3][k:-1]
    h[2][2:5]=[sorted(h[2][2:5]).pop(1-i)for i in t]                        # Adjusting arrangment of third player to match scoring arrangment per round
    return h
```

Comment: `as it is impossible for the lowest scoring hand to win a trick without gaining a score of two or having an illegal move prior` can't it be "♣9 ♣8  ♣7  ♣6; ♡2 ♠5  ♠6  ♠7"?